# jQuery Copy to clipboard, manual text entered without ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use the following code that copies text to your clipboard, but when I click on the text, it does not copy anything, and I have no JS errors in the console. (I'm sure it's something to do with the use of "element" within the jQuery, but I'm not sure how to fix it.)

I do not want to assign an ID to the Phone number, only enter the number manually within the "onclick" event.

**Html**

```
<p style="text-decoration:underline;" onclick="copyToClipboard('1-888-888-8888')"> My Phone Number</p>
```

**jQuery**

```
  function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in this line:

```
$temp.val($(element).text()).select();
```

Change this into this:

```
$temp.val(element).select();
```

And you will see the result